# Make Mysql errors caught in c# user friendly

Tags: c#, mysql, error-handling

I am trying to return user friendly error message when a Mysql Exception is thrown in c#. I am currently returning the exception message but that message is not very user friendly. So I was wondering if any one of you had any trick that does not require any fancy regex parsing of the error messages received to display them to the user in a manner that would make sense to them.

I am trying to stay away from complex validation code prior to inserting/updating/deleting a record but that seems to be the only way ... unless you know better!

Comment: Every mysql error has an error code: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html   You can write your own error messages for those.

Comment: Hey Marc, that seems like a good idea but from which method in the exception object can I get this code ? I only seem to be getting the MySql.Data Exception and the message from the db without the error code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) pointed that every Mysql error has an error code, so you can catch a `MySqlException` using a `try ... catch` block like this:

```
try
{

}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    int errorcode = ex.Number;
}
```

So you can write a case statement to provide the error message for each error code, here are a list of [**server error codes and messages**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html).

Comment: Yes I figured my main problem was I was catching Exception and not the specific MySqlException so I did not have access to the Number attribute. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try catching the specific sql error message and display it

```
Try

Catch ex as SqlException
'''sql specific error message
''ie: 
response.write("oops! error message: " & ex.message)
Catch ex as Exception
'''any other runtime error messages
End Try
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, this is what I am currently doing but a duplicate key on insertion is not a message easily understandable by everyone I am trying to build on those error a user-friendly message like "the value entered is already present in the system"

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of translating error messages into wording your average Joe will understand.  What i've done in the past is use a resource file and put in one column the .Net exception message and then in the second column the enduser translation.  Very tidious, but for that project i had a requirement that the error had to be easy to understand by the user.  Exceptions are really designed for programmers to handle programmatically (translate intoa a userfriendly message, log the error, etc) to handle errors more gracefully.